# TextView to Bitmap, alignment issues

Tags: android, android-canvas, textview, android-bitmap

I am facing a situation in which I need to draw bitmap for a given text. I tried to render a TextView with required properties and then draw its bitmap using canvas. My try looks like this:

```
TextView nameTv = new TextView(context);
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

nameTv.layout(0, 0, 200, 200);
nameTv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
nameTv.setText("Test");
nameTv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

nameTv.draw(canvas);
```

The problem with this code is that the text on TextView not center aligned, which I require.
Any suggestions are welcomed :)

Thanks,
Ammar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in measuring. You not calling measure for that and it don't have properly size. Call nameTv.measure() before layout().

Call measure like this:

```
int measureSpecWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(200, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
int measureSpecHeight = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(200, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
nameTv.measure(measureSpecWidth, measureSpecHeight);
```

Comment: nameTv.measure() didn't worked. Now text is aligned top right instead of center.

Comment: Which params you passed to measure method?

Comment: I invoked nameTv.measure(200, 200)

Comment: I will be happy to see :).

Comment: @Ammar I updated my answer. Also, I recommend to read this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html